# 3-divisibility of Manin constant for elliptic curves with 3-torsion

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, birch-swinnerton-dyer

Let $E/\mathbb{Q}$ be an elliptic curve with $E(\mathbb{Q}) \cong \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ (not necessarily $\Gamma_0$-optimal). Does $3$ necessarily divide one of: the Manin constant (not necessarily $1$), the Tamagawa product, and the size of the Tate-Shafarevich group? I checked this for all curves in the LMFDB with conductor less than 10,000 and can't find any counter-examples.

Here is some context. The Birch–Swinnerton-Dyer quotients for rank zero elliptic curves $E/\mathbb{Q}$ generally have square-free denominators, due to Proposition 1.1 in [Lorenzini's paper](http://www.numdam.org/item/10.5802/aif.2664.pdf) that classifies possible cancellations between the torsion and Tamagawa numbers. There are exceptions, notably when $E(\mathbb{Q}) \cong \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$, where Lemma 2.26 gives an infinite family where the Tamagawa product is $1$, or when $E(\mathbb{Q}) \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, which I'm not interested in. However, adding the size of the Tate-Shafarevich group into the picture makes the cancellation hold for many almost semistable elliptic curves with $E(\mathbb{Q}) \cong \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$, as proved in Theorem 3.1 in [Melistas's paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2211.08147.pdf). Moreover, adding the Manin constant into the picture seems to make the cancellation hold unconditionally, as noted in Example 3.8 (and Example 2.6, but I didn't check LMFDB for this).

I don't know how to prove results on the Manin constant, so this was just something I observed experimentally. [Cesnavicius](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.02951.pdf) proved that the Manin constant of a semistable $\Gamma_0$-optimal elliptic curve is $1$, but I can't find any existing literature proving that the Manin constant is not $1$ for families of elliptic curves that are not $\Gamma_0$-optimal. I'm trying to show that the special L-value (times the Manin constant) has square-free denominators, so a direct way to prove this without assuming BSD would be ideal.

Comment: Very well formulated and well referenced question.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps there is an elementary answer after all. Here is my attempt at a partial answer assuming BSD.

Let $c_0(E)$ denote the Manin constant of $E$, and let $L(E)$ denote the special L-value of $E$ divided by its real period. For any odd prime $p$ not dividing the conductor of $E$, the Hecke operator $T_p$ acts on the space of modular symbols of $E$, and by pairing up the periods (similar to [Proposition 7 of Wiersema–Wuthrich](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2004.05492.pdf)), it can be shown that $c_0(E)L(E)|E(\mathbb{F}_p)|$ is integral. There are stronger integrality statements replacing $|E(\mathbb{F}_p)|$ by the torsion subgroup in [Proposition 4.6 of Agashe](https://www.math.fsu.edu/%7Eagashe/math/bsd.pdf), but it's only stated for optimal quotients.

If $3$ does not divide $c_0(E)$, then $L(E)|E(\mathbb{F}_p)|$ is integral at $3$, so by BSD it suffices prove that $|E(\mathbb{F}_p)|$ is divisible by $3$ but not $9$, for some odd prime $p$. This argument does work when $E$ has good reduction at $3$, in which case the Hasse bound forces $|E(\mathbb{F}_3)|$ to be $3$ or $6$. I wonder if the elementary integrality argument can be adapted to work with the Hecke operator $U_3$ when $E$ has bad reduction at $3$.

In general, we would have to inspect the mod $9$ Galois image of $E$ to obtain a Frobenius at $p$ for which $|E(\mathbb{F}_p)|$ is divisible by $3$ but not $9$. I have looked at all 42 possible $3$-adic Galois images of $E$ (given the rational $3$-isogeny coming from torsion), thanks to [the classification in Corollary 1.3.1 and 12.3.3 in Rouse–Sutherland–Zureick-Brown](https://browse.arxiv.org/pdf/2106.11141.pdf). In all cases except the subgroup labels 9.72.0.1, 9.72.0.5, and 9.72.0.12, there are primes $p$ that work, but in these three cases (e.g. the isogeny class with Cremona label 54b) I am stuck.

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated!

EDIT: I think I found an argument involving a case-bash that finishes off the proof, but I would still prefer a nicer conceptual proof to this, so I'll not accept my own answer to await a better argument.

The subgroup label 9.72.0.5 has $E(\mathbb{Q}) \cong \mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z}$ (since its mod $9$ image fixes a line) and the subgroup label 9.72.0.12 has $E(\mathbb{Q}) \cong 1$ (since its mod $3$ image does not fix anything), so we can ignore these cases. The remaining subgroup label 9.72.0.1 has mod $3$ image that is Cartan, and I claim that in this case there is some prime $p$ such that the Tamagawa number $c_p$ is divisible by $3$.

Now the elliptic curves with $c_p = 1$ and non-trivial torsion are completely classified thanks to the work of Lorenzini (aforementioned) and [Theorem 1.2 and Theorem 5.2 in Barrios–Roy](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2104.10337.pdf). For elliptic curves with $3$-torsion, by following the argument in the proof of Theorem 1.2, one could read from the table in Theorem 3.5 that $c_p$ is divisible by $3$ if $E$ is not isomorphic to the elliptic curve $y^2 + a^3xy \pm a^6y = x^3$ for any $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ (the other possibility $y^2 + ay^2 = x^3$ has CM, and thanks to the Rouse–Sutherland–Zureick-Brown classification, CM mod $9$ images have primes $p$ such that $|E(\mathbb{F}_p)|$ is divisible by $3$ but not $9$). Thus it suffices to prove that if $E$ is isomorphic to an elliptic curve of this form, which by a change of variables is just $y^2 + xy \pm \tfrac{1}{a^3}y = x^3$, then it cannot have mod $3$ image that is Cartan.

Finally, mod $3$ images can be read off from the $j$-invariant thanks to [Theorem 1.2 in Zywina](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1508.07660.pdf). By a simple calculation with $t = \tfrac{27}{a^3 - 27}$, our elliptic curve has $j$-invariant of the form $J_3(t)$, so Theorem 1.2 establishes that it has mod $3$ image that is Borel, which is in particular not Cartan.

I suppose this final argument isn't that elementary after all.